# Prolog Binary Tree

Tags: prolog, binary-tree, predicate

I have an assignment in which I have to design a binary tree in Prolog and then implement some predicates for it(E.g. Insert, traversal, search and height.)

I am confident enough to implement them but as a starting point I was given this:

A binary tree can be defined in terms of 2 predicates:

emptyBT, the empty binary tree

btTree(N,T1,T2) that is true if N is the root of a binary tree with left subtree T1 and right subtree T2, where all the items in T1 are less than or equal to N and all the items in T2 are greater than N.

Could someone point me in the direction of the BT implementation using the above two predicates? I have searched online and through some Prolog books and they all define BTs differently and this has confused me somewhat.

Comment: `BTTree(N,...` is not Prolog syntax to start with.

Comment: bTTree(N,..)? Is that proper Prolog syntax?

Comment: Please consult a Prolog book first: Art of Prolog, Bratko, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
isEmptyBinTree( btEmpty ).
```

that's one. Right?

```
isNonEmptyBinTree( btTree(N,Left,Right) ):-
  ( isEmptyBinTree(Left)
    ;                            % or
    isNonEmptyBinTree(Left),
    getMaxElement(Left,Max), 
    N >= Max
  ) ,                            % and
  ( isEmptyBinTree(Right)
    ;                            % or
    isNonEmptyBinTree(Right),
    ....                         % can you complete this definition?
  ).
```

that's the other one. Now all that's left is to define the missing `getMaxElement/2` and `getMinElement/2` predicates. Both of them can assume their argument is *not* an empty binary tree:

```
getMinElement( btTree(N,Left,_), M ) :- 
    isEmptyBinTree(Left),
    M = N.                                 % right?
getMinElement( btTree(_,Left,_), M ) :-
    getMinElement( ... , M ).
```

Answer (score 0):

`btEmpty` is not a predicate; it is an atom. `btTree/3` is not a predicate either; it is a compound term. If your assignment calls those two predicates then there is something very fishy.

The definitions in different sources might be different, but they are all probably some variation of an atom representing the empty tree and a term with arity 3 representing a non-empty node.

Anyway, this for example is a tree representing the numbers {1, 2, 3}:

```
btTree(2, btTree(1, btEmpty, btEmpty), btTree(3, btEmpty, btEmpty))
```

This is a nested compound term. The tree structure should be recognizable: from your example, the `N`, the actual element at that tree node, is always the first argument of the term, and the left and right sub-trees are `T1` and `T2`.

And just to get you started, this is a very simple predicate to traverse a tree defined like this in-order:

```
in_order(btTree(_, Left, _), N) :-
    in_order(Left, N).
in_order(btTree(N, _, _), N).
in_order(btTree(_, _, Right), N) :-
    in_order(Right, N).
```

This delivers elements upon backtracking.